# Customizing Treecell: Placement of Arrow Icon

Tags: css, javafx, treeview

I'm trying to make a customized TreeView using CellFactory and Css.

This is what I have so far:

[image: What I have so far]

I want to center the arrow so that it points to the middle of the TreeCell.

Problem is, I don't know how. I have tried padding, but this only scales the icon.

It might be worth mentioning that the arrow is not part of the HBox I load in to represent the treeCell.

Here's my CSS:

```
.tree-cell{
-fx-content-display: CENTER;
-fx-position-shape: true;
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#c9e9d1 20%, #9dbda5 80%);
}
.tree-cell .tree-disclosure-node .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: #facf46;
    -fx-padding: 0.666666em; /* 4 */
    -fx-shape: "M 0 -4 L 4 0 L 0 4 z";
    -fx-content-display: center;
}

.tree-cell:expanded .tree-disclosure-node .arrow {
    -fx-content-display: center;
    -fx-background-color: #facf46,


    -fx-rotate: 90;
}

.tree-cell:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #dfffe7;
}

.tree-cell:selected{
    -fx-background-color: #4f88da;
}
```

In these two links, there's code for how I represent TreCells by HBox:

[Customizing TreeCells using cell factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737854/customizing-treecells-using-cell-factory)
[JavaFX TreeView: setGraphic() for different levels of treeItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754768/javafx-treeview-setgraphic-for-different-levels-of-treeitem)

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Have edited to include some code.

Comment: One way using which you can vertically center all the elements is to set `display: table` on the parent container which I believe is `.tree-cell` and then set `display: table-cell, vertical-align: niddle` on all of its child-elements. Anyways, is it available to be viewed on some website so that the CSS can be debugged?

Comment: THanks for the tips, but I don't think it's possible to apply all the normal CSS commands to .tree-cell or other components in JavaFX. I do have an ugly solution now that I can post soon.

Unfortunately, I do not have this on a website, but thanks for replying all the same.

Comment: I see that it's pretty much the same problem, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've found for this requires knowing the height of the hbox. Let's say we set its pref height to 80px.

First, right after showing the scene on the `start()` method, we look for the node with the arrow, which is a `StackPane`, and set its properties:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ...
    primaryStage.show();

    StackPane sp=(StackPane)tree.lookup(".tree-disclosure-node");
    sp.setPrefSize(80,80);
    sp.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    sp.setPadding(new Insets(20));
}
```

This is not enough, since on the `updateItem()` method of the custom cell, after adding the hbox, the cell contains also a `StackPane` that is overriden everytime this method is called, so we need to get this stack pane and set the same properties again:

```
@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (item != null) {
        if (getTreeView().getTreeItemLevel(getTreeItem())==1) {
            setGraphic(this.hBox);
        }else if (getTreeView().getTreeItemLevel(getTreeItem())==2){
            setGraphic(this.hBoxLeaf);
        }
        // look for the StackPane
        this.getChildrenUnmodifiable().stream().filter(StackPane.class::isInstance)
                .forEach(p->{
                    StackPane sp=(StackPane)p;
                    sp.setPrefSize(80,80);
                    sp.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                    sp.setPadding(new Insets(20));
                });
    } else {
        setGraphic(null);
    }
}
```

We don't need any extra css properties, so this is enough:

```
.tree-cell{
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#c9e9d1 20%, #9dbda5 80%);
}

.tree-cell .tree-disclosure-node .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: #facf46;
    -fx-shape: "M 0 -4 L 4 0 L 0 4 z";
}

.tree-cell:expanded .tree-disclosure-node .arrow {
    -fx-rotate: 90;
}
.tree-cell:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #dfffe7;
}
.tree-cell:selected{
    -fx-background-color: #4f88da;
}
```

Finally, we get something like this:

[image: Centered arrow on custom cell]

Comment: I will check if this works as soon as I get the time and get back to edit this comment :) Thanks!